# Does zero intersection number between simple closed curves on a torus imply that they can be split?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let $C_1$ and $C_2$ be two simple (with no self intersections) closed curved on n-holed torus where $n >1$. Suppose also that any of $C_1$ and $C_2$ is not homologous to zero in the n-holed torus. The curves $C_1$ and $C_2$ intersect transversally such that the oriented intersection number is zero. Does zero intersection number imply that $C_1$ and $C_2$ can be split by isotopy moves?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

Think of a ring of 3 holes (like a bunch of bagels stuck together) arranged around a circle (see figure). This is a 4-holed torus. Let's imagine it's lying flat on a table. Then you can draw the orange curve (the dotted part is "below") and the green curve, each of them non-null-homologous, intersecting in 0 (algebraically) points, but they cannot be made disjoint through isotopy.

[image]

Comment: I might be lacking in imagination here, but does one really need the hole on the lower right?

Comment: Probably not. OP did not ask for the simplest example, and this one was easy for me to draw without further thought, so I did.

Comment: I got it. Thank you so much Hughes.

Comment: @user113715 If this answered your question, your should consider accepting this answer.